# Странный сайт-зеркало

Tags: поддержка

Нашёл в [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/728535/227016) ссылку на сайт-зеркало `http://qaru.site`

Насколько я понимаю, там на главной выводятся топовые вопросы, а внутри вопросов большое количество рекламы.

Кто-нибудь что-нибудь знает про этот сайт?

Comment: Что-нибудь про сайт не знаю, зато знаю, что надо делать. Предлагаю закрыть вопрос как дубликат

Comment: @AK, да, спасибо

Comment: Рискую прослыть сеошником, но предлагаю не оставлять ссылок на этот сайт на нашем сайте